# How can I get the device name in Android?

Tags: android

How can I get the device name programmatically in Android?

Comment: check out this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Android Phone Model Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

To display the device name/model in android use:

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
String str = android.os.Build.MODEL;
tv1.setText(str);
```

[Link to Android Build Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

Comment: Is there any work around to get the name not model like Samsung galaxy S. because no one is aware about model numbers only people knows handset with their names

Comment: Looks at my answer below to get the manufacturer details too .

Comment: This is model, not name of device

Answer (score 33):

You can get the device name from android.provider.Settings using :

```
Settings.Global.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "device_name")
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it provides the actual device name that the user can modify. The other answers give the device manufacturer name and device model.

Comment: what is the min Android version support this?

Comment: Settings.Global.getString(requireContext().contentResolver, Settings.Global.DEVICE_NAME), Android Studio tells min API level is 25

Answer (score 31):

```
android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER + android.os.Build.MODEL
```

Comment: In Google Nexus devices that were made by LG - this will give you the wrong string - "LGE Nexus 5". You should use  android.os.Build.BRAND + android.os.Build.MODEL.

Answer (score 12):

As others mentioned, you can use `Build.MODEL`, `Build.DEVICE` and you can get lot more info about device. Go to [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) to read more about `Build` class. BTW remember to import/add `import android.os.Build;`.

A simple example:

```
StringBuffer infoBuffer = new StringBuffer();

infoBuffer.append("-------------------------------------\n");
infoBuffer.append("Model :" + Build.MODEL + "\n");//The end-user-visible name for the end product.
infoBuffer.append("Device: " + Build.DEVICE + "\n");//The name of the industrial design.
infoBuffer.append("Manufacturer: " + Build.MANUFACTURER + "\n");//The manufacturer of the product/hardware.
infoBuffer.append("Board: " + Build.BOARD + "\n");//The name of the underlying board, like "goldfish".
infoBuffer.append("Brand: " + Build.BRAND + "\n");//The consumer-visible brand with which the product/hardware will be associated, if any.
infoBuffer.append("Serial: " + Build.SERIAL + "\n");
infoBuffer.append("-------------------------------------\n");
    /* Android doc:
        This 'Serial' field was deprecated in API level O.
        Use getSerial() instead.
        A hardware serial number, if available.
        Alphanumeric only, case-insensitive. For apps targeting SDK higher than N_MR1 this field is set to UNKNOWN.
    */

//I just used AlertDialog to show device information
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setTitle("Device information:");
dialog.setMessage(infoBuffer);//StringBuffer which we appended the device informations.
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to get android device name you have to add only a single line of code:

```
android.os.Build.MODEL;
```

Copy and paste the following code in your projects `onCreate()`:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
String str = android.os.Build.MODEL;
tv1.setText(str);
```

Comment: this code is for getting Device name how do i get device profile name??

Answer (score 6):

To get the phone name, for instance: Galaxy S5 or the like, just add this to your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.jaredrummler:android-device-names:1.0.9'
```

Then sync your project, when it finishes, go to your Java class and use this code:

```
String mDeviceName = DeviceName.getDeviceName();
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 5):

The name and model of your Android Device can be found like this:

```
String manufacturerModel = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + android.os.Build.MODEL;
```

Comment: Build.Model often is a kind of cryptic Model name; eg Samsung SM-T395 is a TabActive 2. So the answer ist precise but not very user friendly if this is used to display to user.

Answer (score 2):

Using following way can get the device name and also in case user modify the device name, it can also get the **updated name**:

```
Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), “bluetooth_name”);
```

Because `bluetooth_name` is **not a documented API**, in case it returns `null`, you can use following code instead: (note that this API is only available **since Android 7.1** and per my testing, it **CANNOT** get the device name immediately after user modified)

```
Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), “device_name”);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get the name that the user set in the "About Phone" "Device name" screen using adb:

```
$ adb shell 'settings get global device_name'
```

Comment: cmd `settings list global` can be used to show list with other available settings