# Specific Device Detection for Android?

Tags: java, android

In what ways can I call for an android app to detect what phone I'm using (like specific model number) in Java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579968/how-can-i-get-the-device-name-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, if you want to display "the end-user-visible name for the end product"(the docs)
:

```
String mDeviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
```

For the industrial name:

```
String mDeviceName = android.os.Build.DEVICE;
```

To get the Manufacturer:

```
String mDeviceManufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
```