# Android app gets device ID and saves into Variable

Tags: java, android, apk

My app needs to do the following thing, right when I turn it on it reads the devices ID (the unique ID each device has) and then saves that into a Variable. I can do the saving no problem.

I was hoping any of you know how to do that? I can't seem to find info on **how to extract this ID from the device**. I need my app to run on a non-root device too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android.os.Build.DEVICE;
android.os.Build.MODEL;
android.os.Build.SERIAL;
```

Comment: where do I put this? Can I call this from my MainActivity? and get any of those 3 variables. Thank you :)

Comment: They are fields in the android.os.Build class. You can import that class and then use them directly or equate them to Strings.

Comment: This is nice also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32605744/6079935

Comment: perfect thank you I'll accept your answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Device ID's can theoretically be changed if the user flashes a new ROM. There's no ID that I'm aware of (though Google may have recently added one, I'm not sure) that lets you know with 100% certainty that you're always on a specific device.