# How to get device's (android)name when we know its Ip address connected under same network?

Tags: android, networking, inetaddress

We got IP addresses of all connected devices under network by using the isReachable() method. (We are checking each IP manually by this method.)

We are intending to get the device name which we assign initially to our android device.

Is there any way of doing it by using Inetaddress?

Comment: Have you tried to use GetHostName()? or getCanonicalHostName()?

Comment: @zach Bubil  : Yes , i tried that. But it was giving same ip address .

Comment: you wanted to get SSID name ?

Comment: try this answer...http://stackoverflow.com/a/6580007/3678308

Comment: I want other devices name through its IP

Comment: @jhaman Das : how to get  SSID through its IP ?

Comment: I think you can send a socket to it and get the device name by the socket.

Comment: @zack Bublil : Thanks . Can you share a piece of code regarding your method ?

Comment: Here is what I have asked in the last day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36567725/how-do-i-get-host-names-by-using-ip-mac-addresses-in-android
Similar to your qn.