# Issues on Android Screen Sizes

Tags: java, android, screen

I am still trying to figure out a solution for this. Ive created a multiple layout on my res folder namely: layout, layout-sw480dp, layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp. Now testing it to real device which is (Samsung galaxy (7 inches) and Alcatel T10(7 inches)) they both go to layout-sw600dp but samsung seems much bigger than alcatel. Most of 7 inches tablet works fine except Samsung. Ive read this link [Screen sizes](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html) and found out that

**The original Samsung Galaxy Tab is an interesting case. Physically it is a 1024x600 7” screen and thus classified as “large”. However the device configures its screen as hdpi, which means after applying the appropriate ⅔ scaling factor the actual space on the screen is 682dp x 400dp. This actually moves it out of the “large” bucket and into a “normal” screen size. The Tab actually reports that it is “large”; this was a mistake in the framework’s computation of the size for that device that we made. Today no devices should ship like this.**

My Samsung galaxy is 3.2 so I am sure that it fits on my requirements.

Does someone know how to handle this kind of problem?Like can I create a new folder for Samsung Galaxy only?

Sorry for my english, it is not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with the above issue for sometime and found that thr was no alternative for this in xml.

You must handle this during run-time, if you only want it for this specific model then u can get the model make during runtime [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically) and then handle the scenario.

I dont see anyway u can have a special folder for samsung, if you find out,please do let me know :)