# Is there any way to specify a folder layouy by inch?

Tags: android, screen-size, android-screen-support

Im doing three folders for different screen sizes (layout-ldpi, layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi). But my Galaxy ace plus don't fit layout-mdpi, if I change the layouts from my galaxy, the other screen sizes don't fit the layout. The problem is all the cell phones considered mdpi have resolution of 320x480, as my Ace plus. the question is: is there any way to specify a folder to only one cellphone (by inch for example)?

Comment: see  : http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: You can try Idolon's answer and then, check if it's Ace plus device.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12707479/2363774

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the size in dp not inch for both width and height. Check the table here to see which one is best for you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: I agree, I usually end up using layout-[large, normal, xlarge] for gingerbread projects.