# Is there a way to detect what kind of phone is being used to run your application

Tags: android

if it is a galaxy Note 2, I want my app to  specifically know that, i tried to look through some documentation, but could not find anything. The closest I could find , is screen size.

Comment: Read this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, you have to mix some of the properties present already: `android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER`, `android.os.Build.MODEL;`, and `android.os.Build.PRODUCT`

I hope, the properties themselves are quite declarative. :D