# How can i find samsung galaxy (S2,S3) model series

Tags: android

Actually my problem is I developed one application.It is properly working in Samsung galaxy S2 and S3 it is not working in Samsung s duos,Samsung ace and lower devices so that I am maintaining a list of model numbers of Samsung galaxy s2 and s3.App checks whether it is s2 or s3 then only it will install otherwise it shows uninstall dailog.For this i need list of model numbers of Samsung galaxy s2 and s3.
     Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like :

[find the device model from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically)

You'll get the o/p and compare for s2 or s3. If you find the device .. run your code or else make a Toast that is not compatible with your device

or

In the uploading  time , you can find some solution

Answer (score 0):

Don't solve this in your app, but solve it in the distribution channel. You do this by blacklisting certain device models in your Google developers console, there should be an option on the page for the release of your app.

Also make sure to look into this not being a problem of Android version compatibility, the Play Store checks this for you.