# Detect if my Unity app is running in a galaxy device to change the gamma

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, galaxy, gamma

I am developing an app for kids with Unity3D 4.3 (2D). The problem is that when I tested it on a galaxy S3 and a galaxy Note, the colors where too saturated. The look of the app in these devices is awful. Is there any way to detect if the app is running on a galaxy device so I can filter the colors or something?

The app is meant to be multiplatform.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There are APIs in the Android SDK that will get you the make/manufacturer of any device.  However, you should dig into the root cause of the problem so that you don't have to try to maintain device-specific patches to your app.

Comment: You meant I should change the color palette of the sprites? That's the other option we are considering. It would be a shame because I think that it looks great the way it is in other devices, but the galaxy family has sold too much to just ignore it :(

Comment: If the problem is a specific compatibility issue, you might need to build different versions of your app for different devices, so that the correct version (with the correct palette) is downloaded to the device.  I can't imagine you're the first person with this issue- the Unity forums probably have suggestions to handle palette compatibility across devices.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will read [this google documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) carefully to see if is there any filter like "device name" or something.

Comment: Here is a question that deals with device/model: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically

I would not bake that into your app, however- create builds that have the appropriate palette for the device so that you don't have to include multiple palettes in your build, which will bloat it.