# how to send information about android device in email subject

Tags: android

I know how to send email from android application and this is my code

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:prayers@e-orthodoxy.net");
    Intent send = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    send.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Review");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(send, "Review"));
```

but how to send

1- device model

2- android version

3- application version

within the subject so they will be wroted automatically

Comment: this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example, into `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` set the device information

```
Intent msg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            String[] recipients = { "mailto:prayers@e-orthodoxy.net" };
            String[] carbonCopies = { "" };
            msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
            msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, carbonCopies);
            msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getDeviceInformation( getResources().getString(R.string.appversion)));
            msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "this is an email");
            msg.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(msg, "Email:"));
```

this is my method, you can send the appversion from strings.xml:

```
public static String getDeviceInformation(String appversion){
    String info = "\n\n"+android.os.Build.MODEL+" "+"/"+android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE+"/"+ appversion;
    return info;
}
```

or you can get the app version from your `Manifest.xml` file

```
public static String getDeviceInformation(){
PackageManager manager = this.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo infoPackage = manager.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
String appversion = infoPackage.versionName;
        String info = "\n\n"+android.os.Build.MODEL+" "+"/"+android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE+"/"+ appversion;
        return info;
}
```

to get the android version you will use :

[android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#RELEASE)

or

[android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT)

Comment: hey you can use the other method DeviceInformation() and you don't need to send the appversion, it will be read from the manifest.xml, thank you =).