# Is there a way to know the details of the Bluetooth Chip in a device?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to know if there is a way to get the details of the bluetooth chip use in a device (other than tearing it down)

Reason: I have a third party lib that does not seem to work with certain phones. The lib once started, blocks any wifi connection..It completely shutdown the Wifi as I get disconnected from the network I am connected to.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of a way to get a bluetooth chip, however please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically) question on how to get the device model. This should hopefully be good enough to detect which models yours will and will not work on (I'm guessing you simply need to exclude older phones).

Comment: Thanks! The lib does not work on a Samsung S5 but works on Oneplus one, Moto G