# What is preventing Google Play from listing my app for my compatible device?

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

My app is not being displayed in the Google Play store.  I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3, 10" device, model GT-P5210 with no SIM card.  Android Version 4.2.2.

EDIT:

Thanks to Andy, I was able to determine that my device is NOT in the compatible devices list in the Google Play store, but I am not sure why!

Here is a Samsung Galaxy 10" device that is supported:

SamsungGalaxy Tab 10.1 GT-P7510

And here is a Samsung Galaxy 10" device that has "wifi" and is supported:

SamsungGalaxy Tab Pro 10.1 picassowifi

But my device is NOT supported:

SamsungGalaxy Tab3 10.1 santos10wifi

These are my permissions, none of which should prevent a 10 inch device with no SIM card:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
android.permission.READ_CALENDAR
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
com.virtumedix.relymd.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

Everything is pretty ordinary, the last two permissions are used for Google Cloud Messenging.  The Gradle SDK targets are:

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 19
```

where SDK 16 is below the Android 4.2.2 installed on the device.

Here are my features:

```
android.hardware.CAMERA
android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS
android.hardware.LOCATION
android.hardware.location.NETWORK
android.hardware.MICROPHONE
android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE
android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN
```

If I browse to the app through the Google Play store, this is the message I get:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Associate your device with an account by logging into the device. Then browse the [Web Play Store](https://play.google.com/store) through a browser whilst logged in to that account (does not have to be on mobile). When you check the app listing and try to install, you should see your device listed. Can it be installed that way? If you see it as incompatible, the reason should also be included there.

Comment: I followed your steps and unfortunately it just says "This app is incompatible with your device"... see the screenshot I just attached to my question

Comment: In your Play Dev Console, check your [device compatibility](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017?hl=en) again. Keep in mind a device can have several different model versions (see [here](http://apps4android.org/smartphone-stats-012114/tablets_by_manufacturer_by_model.htm) for your Samsung Tablet). I think you may have gotten your device model wrong.

Comment: How can I match my device with the unique identifiers on the compatiblity list?  For example my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10" could be a "Tab3" device or "Tab3 10.1", and I'm not sure which of these applies to my device:  "santos10wifi", "lt01wifi", "lt01wifikx", "lt02wifi"  I tried googling those strings and have not been able to determine what they are and how they match my device

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically) should help. I'm pretty sure you want [Build.DEVICE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#DEVICE).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Andy's comments, I was able to use the helper class in this questions answer

[Get Android Phone Model Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically)

To find the name of my device that matched the name in the Google Play compatibility list.  I also narrowed down the offending permission:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

For whatever reason my Samsung Galaxy Tab3 10.1 santos10wifi device does not support this hardware feature.  I'm required to use this feature for the OpenTok library in my app.