# How to make an app display the same data in 2 different devices?

Tags: android, database

I want to make an app that can make "groups" of people who have this app, and display the same information for the people in that group.
Lets say for an instance that the only information would the name of the group. I want everybody who is in the group can see it or change it.
What exactly should I use to make somehing like this?

Edit:

What I want is like that: Imagine Whatsapp but without the chat and stuff, but that kind of group. I want people the have the app only see some data and be able to acreate groups that makes other people who joined this group see the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group users, using the device model, go check out this link to know how to get the phone model. 
[Get Android Phone Model Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically)
In your app you need to make switch, using the retrieved model.
If you want to group people using other properties, then please detalize your question.

Comment: Well, what I want is like that: Imagine Whatsapp but without the chat and stuff, but that kind of group. I want people the have the app only see some  data.

Answer (score 0):

Think the best approach would be a log-in system, so everyone has his own account. Then couple groups to the users (or users on the groups, depending on how many groups the user can join), which are coupled to the data you want them to share.

Or if you want people to just be able to join one group, you could make one account for the whole group, and treat the account as a group.

Comment: I just updated the question with the example, that should be more clear.

Comment: @Cas Think you should still go for the same system, you need users to know which person belongs to which group. The groups could have all kind of different data coupled to it. If this is not the answer you're looking for you, then please specify what it is you exactly want to know.