# Get TV - device model number

Tags: android

How can I get Tv device model number(platform - Android and iOS).

Example:
I'm discovering Tv's on the local network.And I get 22PFK4109/12 or something similar for my Phillips TV.

Is there any similar libraries available ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12707479/3257513)

this will give you the model
like Philips

see also:

```
 String brand = Build.BRAND; // for getting BrandName
 String model = Build.MODEL; // for getting Model of the device
```

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. I would like to connect to the TV with an android device(Phone,tablet) and get the TV model number.

Comment: ok ,so the most close way is to get resolution from screen like 1920X1080. 
you can't get data from tv.