# Get Android Phone Specs Programmatically

Tags: android, android-hardware

I am trying to classify Android phones Running my Apps by something related to the performance. I want to cut out all low quality devices to look at performance/crash rates on good quality phones.

I have the Device Model. For example, on the Samsung Galaxy S6 the value of Build.MODEL could be "SM-G920F", "SM-G920I", or "SM-G920W8". There is a related post about how to convert these into something human readable. [Get Android Phone Model Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically)

I would like to just group phones by quality of the device. The first thought that comes to mind is processor/GPU or resolution. Is there such a lookup table for the specs like there is for the name [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en-GB)?

Comment: Facebook has a library that classifies phones by "year class"-  about what year they would have been high end models.  See https://code.facebook.com/projects/1552773164984484/device-year-class/

Answer (score 0):

You can use mobile device API https://specsapi.cc. Here is the cURL example:

```
curl -X GET “https://specsapi.cc/specification?limit=1&name=iphone%20xs%20max&year=2018” -H “accept: application/json”
```

They have several ready to use API client [enter link description here](https://github.com/specsapi/specsapi-clients)