# Get user agent in android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

Is there any way to get the user agent or model of the android wear programatically?

Something like this

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4; Moto 360 Build/KNX01S)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) WIB/0.9.8 Mobile Safari/537.36

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using [UseragentAPI](https://useragentapi.com/docs) which can be used in device detection, increased accuracy and new useragent types. This can be used to detect useragent types for wearables.

For successful HTTP requests, an example response would be:

```
{
    "data": {
        "ua_type": "Desktop",
        "os_name": "Linux",
        "browser_name": "Chrome",
        "browser_version": "58.0.3029.110",
        "engine_name": "WebKit",
        "engine_version": "537.36"
    }
}
```

If you're only looking for the Android Wear model, this [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12707479) which works perfectly on watch might also help.