# how can I make an app not to work on certain phones?

Tags: java, android

Can I make my android app not work on certain Android phones ? For example, if I don't want my app to work on Samsung J5 2016 Phones, can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm going to edit your question a bit to remove extraneous information and improve grammar - this is so it is more useful for others in future.

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en

Comment: your question is basically `how to get phone model`, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Android Phone Model Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily by using the Build variable in your condition.

android.os.Build.MODEL

android.os.Build.BOARD;

android.os.Build.BRAND;

android.os.Build.PRODUCT

```
if(android.os.Build.MODEL.equalIgnoreCase("Device Model")){ finish();}
```

Comment: `==` is not a way to compare strings

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the model and show some dialog for non-supporting devices.

```
String myDeviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;

if(myDeviceModel.equals("someBoringDevice")){
   //show alert dialog
   //finish()
   return;
}
```

if you have more then one abandoned devices. simple call this in for loop.

```
String myDeviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
for(String deviceModel:modelArray){  
    if(myDeviceModel.equals(deviceModel)){
       //show alert dialog
       //finish()
       return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro for your help, can you please tell where can i insert different Device Models here in for loop

Comment: @IssamElMourabit He already told you. In the above example code, they would be stored in `modelArray`. If you don't know how arrays work, you might want to go through some beginner Java courses before diving futher into Android development.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just check for the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.
For example, if you want to block android 7,
check for the version code:

> public static final int LOLLIPOP = 21;
>
> public static final int LOLLIPOP_MR1 = 22;

Because API Level 21 and 22 are android 7 version. 23 is Nougat.