# How to check if device has 3.5mm Jack or type c progmatically without attaching the earphones

Tags: android

I am trying to find out what kind of ear jack device supports . I mean 3.5 mm or type C or USB etc.

I got some code which detect what kind of headset is plugged , but I want to check ear jack type without plugging earphones into device.

Comment: out of curiosity but why?

Comment: I get that you want to know if it exists, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something which you should figure out by yourself. 
As a developer (in theory) you should not care what the hardware is, but what features it supports.
This is the case with the headset- you're most likely able to detect some vendor string of the headset.

Here's some workaround you could try to guess the jack type:
- You should be able to extract device info. Something like in here: [Get Android Phone Model programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically)
- Then keep a list of the device -> jack port to "extract" that information.

Keep in mind this would be a tedious work and won't be able to detect jacks in 100%.

If you provide more context on why do you need exactly the kind of port, someone might give a better suggestion.